# Bringing information to a 2nd php file, but SESSION isn't the answer

Tags: php, sql, session-variables

I've got file1.php and file1.php. I want an ID(stored in a database) from file1.php to file2.php, but I link to the 2nd page via an `<a href=` And what ID number that has to go to file2.php depends on what link I click. So `SESSIONS` probably wont do. I tried it with `SESSIONS` but it only remembers 1 ID number when I tested it.

This is the line in file1.php which it is all about:

```
while ($thread = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
<a href="thread.php?thread_id={$thread['thread_id']}"> {$thread['title']} </a>
}
```

This while loop makes sure every different title in my database gets a link(to the file2.php) with the necessary information that belongs to the thread_id. (thread_id is the only thing in my database that **has** to be different from the others)

So now to show it in file2.php I got this:

```
$sql_result = $mysqli2->query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE thread_id = '".The ID Number of the link of file1.php."'");
    while ($thread = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
echo <<<EOT
        <table>
            <tr>
                <tr><td> {$thread['title']}</td></tr>
                <tr><td> {$thread['description']}</td></tr>
                <tr><td> {$thread['username']}</td></tr>
                <tr><td> {$thread['date_made']}</td></tr>
            </tr>       
</table>
EOT;
```

to show the information that belongs to the thread_id.
How do I do this?

Comment: It looks as though you are already doing this with thread_id by using GET instead of sessions. If you are looking to add another ID, just use thread.php?thread_id=1234&other_id=9876

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By clicking that link your not storing anything in a session.

You need to use `$_GET`

Example:

```
$thread_id = $_GET['thread_id'];

if(!is_numeric($thread_id)){
   // Exit the script as the Thread ID isn't numeric or do something else
   echo 'THREAD ID NOT NUMERIC';
   exit;
}

$sql_result = $mysqli2->query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE thread_id = '".$thread_id."'");
    while ($thread = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
echo <<<EOT
        <table>
            <tr>
                <tr><td> {$thread['title']}</td></tr>
                <tr><td> {$thread['description']}</td></tr>
                <tr><td> {$thread['username']}</td></tr>
                <tr><td> {$thread['date_made']}</td></tr>
            </tr>       
</table>
EOT;
```

You MUST filter the input that comes from the `$_GET` variable as this is an easy SQL injection vector.

Comment: Now, SQL injection goes here :p

Comment: Yes - which I was just updating the post with.

Answer (score 0):

```
$link=$mysqli2->real_escape_string($_GET['thread_id']);
$sql_result = $mysqli2->query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE thread_id = '$link'");
```

Comment: I don't see what can be badly formatted in: $link=$mysqli2->real_escape_string($_GET['thread_id']);

Answer (score 0):

Using the `$_SESSION` to solve such a problem is not the best idea but you're not doing anything with the session in your code so I'm assuming you found out about that already.

Basically you're on the right path, the way you create your link list is fine!

Now, on the new page, you want to retrieve that ID from the querystring again, and that's where the `$_GET` global array comes into play.

A proper way of retrieving data from the db by using params from the query string would be:

```
if (!isset($_GET['thread_id'])) {
    // route back to the list or throw an error or something
}

// cast the param to int to sanitize it, 
// no real_escape_string needed in the int case
$thread_id = (int) $_GET['thread_id'];

// get the info from the database BUT use parameterized queries!
$stmt = $mysqli2->prepare("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE thread_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param($thread_id);
$stmt->execute();
```